# dart: How will the parent's data change?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html

I need to change the data in the parents, how to do it right?

parent

```
class Parent{
   int testText = 1;
}
```

child

```
class Child extends Parent{
   @Output()
   open(){
     int testText = 2;
   }
}
```

Data change, but only in the child. How do I change the data in the parent class?

Answer (score 1):

@Output annotations can only be put on Stream data structures. So you need something like this:

```
class Child extends Parent{
   final _open = StreamController<int>();

   @Output()
   Stream get open => _open.stream;

   onOpen() { _open.add(2); }
}
```

In the parent template:

```
<child-comp (open)="testText = $event"></child-comp>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you have basically 3 ways how to do it:

**1)** Using some controller which will be injected in constructor and both child and parent will listen and fire events.

If you want more component-like aproach, then:

**2)** You can use data binding

```
<parent #myParent>
  <child (onSomething)="myParent.doSomething($event)"></child>
</parent>
```

in this solution, you will use `@Output()` in the child component.

**3)** You can inject the parent component (ensure that the parent is visible by adding `visibility: Visibility.all,` to the parent component anotation). Then you can simply use `_parent.whatever()`.

```
@Component(
  selector: 'parent',
  styleUrls: ['...'],
  templateUrl: '...',
  directives: [...],
  visibility: Visibility.all,
)
class Parent implements OnInit {
  void doSomething() => print('yolo');

  List<Child> children = [];

  void registerChild(Child child) => children.add(child);
}

@Component(
  selector: 'child',
  styleUrls: ['...'],
  templateUrl: '...',
  directives: [...],
)
class Child implements OnInit {
  Parent _parent;

  Child(this._parent);

  @override
  void ngOnInit() {
    _parent?.registerChild(this);
  }

  @HostListener('click')
  void onClick() {
    _parent.doSomething();
  }
}
```